# What is wrong with my time syntax when I'm creating this trigger?

Tags: database, triggers, mysql-workbench

This is the problem. Create a trigger named trg_late_return that will write the correct value to DETAIL_DAYSLATE in the DETAILRENTAL table whenever a video is returned. The trigger should execute as a BEFORE trigger when the DETAIL_RETURNDATE or DETAIL_DUEDATE attributes are updated. The trigger should satisfy the following conditions:

If the return date is null, then the days late should also be null.

If the return date is not null, then the days late should determine if the video is returned late.

If the return date is noon of the day after the due date or earlier, then the video is not considered late, and the days late should have a value of zero (0).

If the return date is past noon of the day after the due date, then the video is considered late, so the number of days late must be calculated and stored.

Here is my code so far. It's giving me a syntax error, specifically on where I have '12:00:00'. Please help me.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_LATE_RETURN
BEFORE UPDATE ON DETAILRENTAL 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.DETAIL_DAYSLATE = 0;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE - OLD.DETAIL_DUEDATE > DATE_FORMAT(NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '12:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.DETAIL_DAYSLATE = DATEDIFF(OLD.DETAIL_DUEDATE, NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE)*-1;
        ELSE
        SET NEW.DETAIL_DAYSLATE = 0;
        END IF;
    END IF;

END;//
delimiter ;
```